# Validating dynamic text box array values in PHP

Tags: php

The issue is that when the second form is displayed the validation doesn't happen the way I need. Irrespective of I have a value or not in `TextBoxEntry` I get the message `Saved`. Ideally if the text box is not empty then only I should have the message `Saved` but even if I don't have  anything I get the message `Saved`

Can someone pls help?

Thanks

Here is the code:

```
<?php 
SESSION_start();
include ("../connection/index.php"); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="One">
        <form name="form1" method="post" action="">

        <?php
        $SQLbrands="SELECT * FROM brands";
        $runBrands=mysqli_query($db, $SQLbrands) or die ("SQL Error");
        $noRow=mysqli_num_rows($runBrands);
        $brndTable = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' id='brndTable1' class='brndTable1'>";
        $brndTable .= "<thead><tr><th class='brT11'>Brand Name</th><th class='brT21'>Variant</th><th class='brT31'>SKU</th><th class='brT41'></th></tr></thead>";
        $brndTable .= "<tbody>";
        while ($reK = mysqli_fetch_array($runBrands))
        {
            $wec = $reK['id']; $wec2 = $reK['bvariant']; $wec3 = $reK['bsku'];
            $brndTable .= "<tbody class='colormine'><tr>";
            $brndTable .= "<td class='brT1'>".$reK["name"]."</td>";
            $brndTable .= "<td class='brT2'>".$reK["address"]."</td>";
            $brndTable .= "<td class='brT3'>".$reK["tphone"]."</td>";
            $brndTable .= "<td class='brT4'><input type='checkbox' name='checkedMe[]' value='$wec' /></td>";
            $brndTable .= "</tr>";
        }
        $brndTable .= "</tbody>";
        $brndTable .= "</table>";


        echo $brndTable;
        ?>  

        <input type="submit" name="sendone" id="sendone" value="OneClick">
        </form>
</div>

<div id="two">
        <?php

            if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
            {   if(!isset($_POST['checkedMe']))
                {echo 'No check boxes are selected!'; return;} else 
                {
                $mohan = "<form method='post' action=''><table border='1' id='myTad'  cellspacing='0' cellpadding='2'>
                    <tr class='tabColor'>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Address</td>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    </tr>";
                foreach($_POST['checkedMe'] as $checkedMe)
                            {
                                $checkedMe=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$checkedMe);
                                $QR = "SELECT bname, bvariant, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$checkedMe'";
                                $rr = mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
                                $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);
                                $rr = $rr->fetch_assoc();

                                $mohan .= "<tr class='sc_eght' ><td class='sc_five'>".$rr['bname']." ".$rr['bvariant']." ".$rr['bsku'];
                                $mohan .="</td>
                                   <td><textarea  style='width:80px;' name='schema[]' id='vtext' class='sc_one' rows='1' cols='1' maxlength='100'></textarea></td>
                                   <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='TextBoxEntry[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two' size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
                                   </tr>";

                            }
                                $mohan .= "<input type='submit' name='sendMe' id='sendMe' value='Save'></table></form>";
                                $_SESSION['cb'] = $mohan; }

                                if(isset($_SESSION['cb'])) 
                                echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
            }   


        if(isset($_POST['sendMe']))
        {
            if(!(isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry']) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == ''))
            {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Empty!"; return;} else  { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}
        }

            ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `if(!(isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry']) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == ''))`

to

`if( !isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry']) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == '')`

Comment: infact I had your suggestion earlier but still I guess the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @JohnEnglish that statement is wrong anyway. Do what drarkayl said.

Comment: @jackflash Thanks man! Will change to that. However prob still persists

Comment: @JohnEnglish since TextBoxEntry is an array, you cannot compare it to an empty string. You have to use `empty()` in order to evaluate if it contains any elements or not.

Comment: didnt notice it was an array. yea so as @jackflash said change to empty(). and then follow with the if statement accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    if(empty($_POST['TextBoxEntry']))
    {
      echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
      echo "Empty!";
    } else  { 
      echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
      echo "Saved!";
    }
```

I just realized that 'TextBoxEntry' is an Array.
Hope it Helps.

Cheers!!

Comment: If $foo == '', then empty($foo) === true. Ever.

Comment: well I just realized "TextBoxEntry" is an Array

Comment: is there an extra bracket on your first line? Yes it is an array. So when in an array this doesnt work. is it?

Comment: @Ricky Dang So you have a suggestion for me?

Comment: Ok now what happens is the table which has "TextBoxEntry" duplicates and message is already printed when the "Save" button is clicked.

Comment: @JohnEnglish As I can see in your input element..you have used name=TextBoxEntry[] so it is an Array..and you can use empty(array_var) to check if its empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!(isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry']) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == ''))` is equal to `if(!isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry'] && $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] != '')` but you need to change it to

```
if(!isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry'] || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == '')
```

other thing is I don't think you need `return` statement in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line of code

```
if(!(isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry']) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == ''))
```

you should have this one

```
if( (!(isset($_POST['TextBoxEntry'])) || $_POST['TextBoxEntry'] == ''))
```

because when you've had you're code, the program took the negation of all conditions . So you need another () to keep the negation only for the first part.

Just try this thing. Hope it works!